# Test multiple template functions with gTest

Tags: c++, templates, googletest

If the following 3 template functions:

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
size_t foo1(array<T, SIZE>& a, size_t start){}

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
size_t foo2(array<T, SIZE>& a, size_t start){}

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
size_t foo3(array<T, SIZE>& a, size_t start){}
```

All three do the same things with the array `a` but with different implementations.

Now I like to set up a google test for all three functions but without C'n'P all the tests itself. I read about "Value-Parameterized Tests" but I can't define a pointer on the template functions itself.

Test may look like:

```
TEST(Foo1, t1) {
    std::array<int, 2> arr = {3,1};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, arr[foo1(arr, 0)]);
}

TEST(Foo2, t1) {
    std::array<int, 2> arr = {3,1};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, arr[foo2(arr, 0)]);
}

TEST(Foo3, t1) {
    std::array<int, 2> arr = {3,1};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, arr[foo3(arr, 0)]);
}
```

(How) is it possible to set up a test case and reuse its tests for all three template functions without wrapping the tests in self-defined functions (with gTest only) ?

I only like to define a test once and "pass" the used function as some kind of test argument to the test.

Thanks in advance :-)

---

EDIT 1:

After long trying I got this running:

```
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
using fooFp = size_t (*)(std::array<T, SIZE>&, size_t);

template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class fooTemplateClass: public ::testing::TestWithParam<fooFp<T, SIZE>> {};

class Tc1 : public fooTemplateClass<int, 1>{};

TEST_P(Tc1 , Fnc) {
    fooFp<int, 1> fnc = GetParam();
    std::array<int, 1> arr = {1};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, arr[fnc(arr, 0)]);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Name, Tc1, ::testing::Values(foo1<int, 1>, foo2<int, 1>, foo3<int, 1>), );
```

But still, this is unhandy because I need to define a class (int this case Tc1) for every template combination. I also don't like that I need to define all template settings within the INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P.

Is there a way to generalize this so that I only need to write something like this:

```
TEST_P(fooTemplateClass<int, 1>, Fnc) {
    std::array<int, 1> arr = {1};
    fooFp<int, 1> fnc = GetParam();
    EXPECT_EQ(1, arr[fnc(arr, 0)]);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Name, fooTemplateClass, ::testing::Values(foo1, foo2, foo3), );
```

I know all template types and sizes at compile time so I can pass them. But at the moment I don't found out how to pass a template class to a TEST_P macro ...

Answer (score 1):

Don't have gtest at hand right now to test it, but I think you could use a single test fixture which derives from `::testing::TestWithParam<std::function<size_t(std::array<T, SIZE>, size_t)>>`. This enables you to write tests using the `TEST_P` macro that can call `GetParam()` to get an instance of type `std::function<size_t(std::array<T, SIZE>, size_t)>`. You could then use this function object to call your method.

Your test fixture, however, would still be a template class due to your T and SIZE template arguments. The first problem with this is, that you can't have a `,` in a macro parameter if it is not surrounded by parenthesis. This could be circumvented by writing your own macro that defines a typedef and exploiting variadic macros. However, you would need to uniquely identify each typedef based on the template arguments to later pass it to INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P. This, however would need some advanced template tricks I am not capable of.

The following code gives you a macro `TEST_T` which can be used as shown

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_(a,b)
#define CONCAT_(a,b) a ## b
#define ARG(arg1, ...) arg1
#define ARG1(arg, ...) CONCAT(arg, ARG( __VA_ARGS__ ))
#define ARG2(arg, ...) CONCAT(arg, ARG1( __VA_ARGS__ ))
#define ARG3(arg, ...) CONCAT(arg, ARG2( __VA_ARGS__ ))

#define TEST_T(test_case_name, test_name, ...) \
    using CONCAT(test_case_name, ARG2( __VA_ARGS__ )) = test_case_name < __VA_ARGS__ >; \
    TEST_P(CONCAT(test_case_name, ARG2( __VA_ARGS__ )), test_name)

TEST_T(fooTemplateClass, Fnc, int, 1) {
    fooFp<int, 1> fnc = GetParam();
    std::array<int, 1> arr = {1};
    EXPECT_EQ(1, arr[fnc(arr, 0)]);
}
```

You would still have to instantiate it with

```
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(Name, fooTemplateClassint1, ::testing::Values(foo1<int, 1>, foo2<int, 1>, foo3<int, 1>));
```

I could not solve this remaining problem, but maybe it helps you to find a solution that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried it but as it seems it's not working. I've edited my original post.

Comment: The first problem is, that you cant have a `,` in a macro parameter is it is not surrounded by parenthesis. This could be circumvented by writing your own macro that defines a typedef and exploiting variadic macros. However, you would need to uniquely identify each typedef based on the template arguments to later pass it to `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P`. This, however would need some advanced template tricks I am not capable of. I played around for several hours but could not fix it. However, I updated my answer...